# Run a Python script in an shell on web browser

Tags: python, shell, terminal, ipython

I'm working on a terminal based game that I created in Python. I'm wondering if it's possible to instead of forcing users to download the scripts, if it's possible to run it in a python shell directly in a browser. I know of many sites that allow you to run Python online, but I'm hoping i can add its own website. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Another thing, would it be possible to prevent the script source from being viewed? This is secondary, but if you know of an easy way I'd love to know.
Thanks!

Comment: Check out [Python Anywhere](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NH2PhXYvrWs) code hosting and virtual environment!